# Syntax error "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't run my Rspec user_spec.rb test due to a syntax error. Too many "end" perhaps in 2 different files? I've added and deleted 'end' in certain places without success.

Syntax error "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)"
require 'spec_helper'

**user_spec.rb**

```
describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  it { should be_valid }

    before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end

describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end


describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
   require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }


    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end
    end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
```

**Terminal Output**

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': /Users/Abraham/code/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation of the code, you would spot more easily the missing `end`

Comment: I will. Where's the missing 'end' ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that you have a bunch of `describe`s that never have `end`s keywords, starting with `describe "when email format is invalid" do` until `describe "when email address is already taken" do`

Put an end on those guys and you're probably done =)

Comment: That's done the job, thanks. I actually missing part of the code for 'user_pages_spec.rb' which is why that isn't working.

Comment: Edited 'user_pages_spec.rb'. Any idea why i'm getting a syntax error?

Comment: With the current code it seems that your 'user_pages_spec.rb' have one extra 'end' at the beginning, here:

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }


    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end (you just finished the describe here, probably removing this one will do the trick, give it a try =))

Comment: that did the trick. Now i just have to deal with the 13 Failures lol! Thank : )

Answer (score 4):

Do you perhaps have one too many here?

```
 describe "when name is too long" do
     before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
     it { should_not be_valid }
 end
 end
```

Comment: Edited 'user_pages_spec.rb'. Any idea why i'm getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case it help someone else. The cause of this error for me was a missing `do` after creating a form with `form_with`. Hope that may help someone else

Answer (score -2):

$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT - that solved the same problem for me